# Including some files from an external Git repo in my root folder (which already has a local repo)

Tags: git

I have an old handcrafted website which is source-controlled with Git, using the default /.git repo folder. There is no remote repo.

I now want to include a GitHub project into the site. 2 out of its 5 files must be in the root folder; one of the other three (index.html) has a filename that conflicts with my existing site. What's the appropriate way to do this so that:

- `git status` or `git diff` will alert me to updates on the GitHub project
- By default, other Git commands like `add`, `commit`… will use my existing personal repo (more of a nice-to-have than a requirement)
- Only 2 of the 5 GitHub repo files will appear in my root folder

Comment: you could do it if you just let everything from some module to stay on that module. You maybe could create a symbolic link inside your root folder to link to files inside the subfolders where you checked out the github projects

Comment: Symlinking from the root folder would allow me to store the external repo in a folder separate from my own `.git`. How should I bring in that repo to give me both the Git integration (`status`, `diff`…) and separation (by default, commits etc. operate on my repo) I want?

Comment: you must have separate git status / git diff's but you can use submodules to put them inside your project (but on a separate tracking)